# Merging the database in oledb connections

Tags: c#, .net, sql, oledb

I have developed c# application with OLEDB connectons.

I have installed that application at two places.

At first place my client has made Entries for property Details(Estate agency app).
This data has got stored in propDetails table.

On another comp he has made entries for purchaser details.
This data has got stored in purchaserDetails table.

Now i want to merge the tables in both the files programatically.

So is there any way in C# so that i can merge the database in two different files?

Comment: Do you mean that you wish to create a table that includes all of the Data? What do you need to merge the Data for? I'm thinking something may not be correct with the structure.

Comment: Is there any Relationship between the two tables?

Comment: no.there are two different access files with 2 tables propDetails and purchaserDetails. In first file consider that propDetails has 10 records and purchaserDetails has no records. And in second file purchaserDetails has 10 records and propDetails has no records. I want to merge them or create third fie such that both the tables has their respective 10 records.

Comment: The table are updated on one database only or both? Do you need to synchronize the two databases again or this is just one shot maintenance activity?

Comment: Steve, you can refer my above comment

Comment: I doesnt matters it should get updated with one db or both. If third databse file with the merging of both dbs is created then also it wi be helpful for me. and its just a short maintanance activity.

Comment: Is the same End User Responsible for recording Data in both Access Files? If so, Why cant these be all in one Relational Database. If the two Tables have related information, I would recommend doing it this way.

Comment: same end user is responcble but since there are thousands of records in both the tables thats why he has hired two different persons sitting on two different machines. One person is making entry for the data which is stored in propDetails table on one machine and another person maing entry for purchaserDetails table. Now entries are finished and they wants all the records (Both the filled tables) in one file.

Comment: I understand that, But with Access you can host the Database on a Network Share, So both Users can edit the same Database file at the same time without colliding. Records are locked when you make a connection, for less than a second. If you have an available network share, host the Access Database there. Is there any space like this available?

Comment: yeah it would possible, but problem is that one of the machine is desktop computer on which one user(hired person) makes entry on office time and another is laptop. so to make entries fast that laptop is carried by another person to his home. so its better i should try out that merging programatically.

Comment: Givent the fact that the one table is updated on one machine and the other on the other machine without a user interfering on the activity of the other one,  then the best course of action is to do this maintenance activity directly using the MS Access Interface . No need to program for this. If you add the MS-Access tag you will get a fast response

Comment: Sorry for all the questions, Just trying to understand exactly what it is you have here. Who will be responsible for the Merge of Data, Will you be passing this off to the Users?